# An application to get statistical data about HTTP Request/Response

Tags: http, utilities, http-request, http-response

I'm looking for an application which takes the address of a website, browses that website, and provides reports based on some user-defined criteria about the HTTP requests/responses. For example, this application should report how many images doesn't have Cach-Control response header, or how many items are more than 25KB in size (including images, scripts, styles, etc.).

I know about [PageSpeed](http://pagespeed.googlelabs.com/) or [WebPageTest](http://www.webpagetest.org/), or Firebug or YSlow and plugins like that. But they don't have customized reports, and you should manually go through each response to check something. Also they are not repeatable. I'm looking for an application in which you enter the parameters once, and then many times you can test a website during its development.

Does such an application exist? Anyone have any reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thing you should be looking at testing tools such as HTTPUnit and/or JMeter.  There are alternatives for both, but you could start by looking at them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @BillThor, I'll take a look at them. :)